# ¿como puedo registrar una venta, y que no se elimine toda la informacion sobre el producto del fichero?

Tags: c

al querer registrar una venta y que se actualice de manera correcta del fichero
funciona correctamente con el ultimo y penultimo producto guardado en el archivo pero al querer vender el primer producto la informacion de este desaparece, o se elimina el resto del registro quedando solo el. que puedo tener en cuenta para solucionar este problema, y agradeceria mucho si pudieran hecharle un vistazo a mi codigo y asi quiza puedan darme un consejo de que podria hacer, lo estoy usando son archivos de acceso aleatorio.
Este es el fragmento de mi codigo que se encarga de la venta:

```
    void vender_producto(){

  bool producto_encontrado= false;
  int codigo_producto=0;
  struct inventario inv;
  int cant_unidades=0;
  FILE *fps;
  FILE *temporal;

  fps = fopen("Registro.dat", "r");
  temporal = fopen("registrotemporal.dat", "a+");

  if(temporal==NULL && fps ==NULL){

    printf("REGISTROS NO ENCONTRADOS \n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("ARCHIVO ABIERTO CON EXITO \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    system("cls");
    printf("INGRESE EL CODIGO DEL PRODUCTO QUE DESEA VENDER: \n ");
    scanf("%d", &codigo_producto);
    rewind(fps);
    fread(&inv,sizeof(inventario),1,fps);
    fseek(temporal, 1*sizeof(inventario), SEEK_SET);

   while(!feof(fps)){

       if(codigo_producto == inv.cod_producto){
          producto_encontrado=true;
          fflush(stdout);
          printf(" \n Codigo del producto: %d",inv.cod_producto);
          printf(" \n Nombre del producto: %s", inv.nom_producto);
          printf(" \n Unidades disponibles: %d", inv.unidades);
          printf(" \n Precio de venta: %f", inv.precio_venta);
          printf(" \n Inversion total en este producto: %f ", inv.inversion);
          fflush(stdout);
          fflush(stdin);

          printf("Digite la cantidad de unidades que vendera del producto: \n "); fflush(stdout);
          scanf("%d", &cant_unidades); fflush(stdin);

          inv.unidades = inv.unidades - cant_unidades;
          inv.inversion = inv.inversion-(cant_unidades * inv.precio_venta);


          fseek(temporal, 1*sizeof(inventario), SEEK_SET);
          fread(&inv,sizeof(inventario),1,fps);

          fwrite(&inv,sizeof(inventario),1,temporal);

          printf("venta finalizada \n");
       } ///fin del if
       else
       {
          fwrite(&inv,sizeof(inventario),1,temporal);

       }///fin del else del if anterior


       if(producto_encontrado=false){
          printf("Registro de producto no encontrado");
       }///fin del if
   }


       fclose(fps);
       fclose(temporal);

       remove("Registro.dat");
       rename("registrotemporal.dat","Registro.dat");

        system("pause");
        system("cls");

  } ///fin del else
```

espero y puedan ayudarme, saludos!!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: pq estas buscando el item si es el primero? no deberias grabar directamente en ese caso?